# write result of for xml raw query to file vb.net

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I have a for xml raw select query that returns a xml string in server2005 and i would like to write that string to a file using vb.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that if you fill a dataset with the result of the sql the first cell is the restult.
How slow was i?!

----------Code Below-------

```
   Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sql As String
        Dim stringxml As String
        Dim SqlCon1 As String = "Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        connection = New SqlConnection(SqlCon1)
        sql = "select * from tblProduct for xml auto"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, SqlCon1)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            stringxml = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
            Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\testings\picktoday.xml")
                writer.Write(stringxml)
            End Using

            MsgBox("Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Instead of using the DataAdapter you may want to make use of a DataReader instead.  It's a bit more lightweight and suits your purposes better.

You can then get the result out of the DataReader with some code similar to this:
stringXML = reader(columnIndex).GetString()

Comment: yeh on further processing i found that there is a limit of 2033 chars when returning XML through SqlDataAdapter. SqlXmlAdapter was the way forward...

Comment: Awesome! I spent a full day messing with dataset.WriteXml, GetXML, LoadXML, etc methods and this was all I actually needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Using strmWrite as System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
    strmWrite.WriteLine(xmlString)
End Using
```

Obviously, just fill in the filePath variable with the directory and name of your file.  The xmlString variable will be your XML.

Comment: I know how to write the string to a file.  I dont know how to get the string from sql. Sorry if i was not specific.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the accepted answer when we have a long output we can get data in multiple rows so we can use the following code

```
dim xmloutput  as string
For Each item As DataRow  In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    xmloutput += item.Item(0)
Next
```